Integrating asp.net webforms with webpack hot reloading
I would like to integrate loading React root elements for each of my .aspx pages.
Currently I have setup the webpack like this :

    const path = require("path");
    const glob = require("glob");
    const webpack = require("webpack"); //to access built-in plugins
    const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
    const fs = require("fs");
    
    module.exports = async (env, argv) => {
    
      
      // npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode=development --env=files=./authorized-dealer/authorized-dealer-4.tsx,./authorized-dealer/authorized-dealer-5.tsx
    
      /** @type {webpack.Configuration} */
      var config = {
        ...(true && {
          cache: {
            type: "filesystem",
            cacheDirectory: path.resolve(__dirname + "/.webpackcache/" + argv.mode + "/", ".temp_cache"),
          }, // stats: "verbose",
        }),
    
        plugins: [
          new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
    
          new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            ...(argv.mode !== "development" && {
              __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__: "({ isDisabled: true })",
            }),
          }),
        ],
        devServer: {
          compress: true,
          port: 9000,
          static: {
            directory: path.join(__dirname, "compiled-ts"),
          },
          proxy: [
            {
              target: "http://localhost:44370",
            },
          ],
        },
    
        mode: argv.mode,
    
        ...(argv.mode === "development" && {
          devtool: "source-map",
        }),
        entry: (glob.sync("./**/**.{ts,tsx}", {
              ignore: [
                // "./**/lib/**",
                "./node_modules/**",
                "./ts/global-variables.d.ts",
                "./API-Documentation/generate-types.ts",
                "./API-Documentation/api.types.ts",
              ],
            })
        ).reduce(function (obj, el) {
          obj[path.parse(el).name] = el;
          return obj;
        }, {}),
    
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              use: "ts-loader",
              exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
          ],
        },
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
        },
        output: {
          filename: "[name].js",
          path: path.resolve(__dirname, "compiled-ts"),
          clean: true,
        },
      };
      //
      return config;
    };


I run this by using the following command :
    npx webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch --mode=development


This builds all of my .ts and .tsx files and places them conveniently under ./compiled-ts
and for loading a react root element, I'm loading the .js file like this :
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master/app.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
    
        <asp:Content ID="MainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="content_body" runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/compiled-ts/dashboard.js"></script>
        </asp:Content>

Now I'm starting to face the issue of the increased amount of .tsx pages in the project, and now the project build time takes around one minute to 2 minutes. I wish to reduce this time by introducing a solution.
My proposal was to create an express server, that acts as a receiver for the requests of loading the .js files. After this express server receives the request to load the .js file, I compile only the requested .tsx file and then serving its content.
While this solution worked for me initially on a test project I'm running, when I try this solution on my current project, it takes around 20 seconds to re-compile (by re-requesting) any changes that I make to the .tsx file.
So I tried making a solution by serving an inner webpack dev server that acts as a hot module reloading server so that I wouldn't have to re-request the sources for 20 seconds.
This is the dev server I have written so far :
    const path = require("path");
    const ReactRefreshPlugin = require("@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin");
    const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require("fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin");
    const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
    const webpackDevServer = require("webpack-dev-server");
    const webpack = require("webpack");
    const express = require("express");
    const proxy = require("express-http-proxy");
    const fs = require("fs");
    const { createProxyMiddleware } = require("http-proxy-middleware");
    
    // const webpackDevServerUrl = "http://localhost:3200";
    // const wsProxy = createProxyMiddleware(webpackDevServerUrl, {
    //   ws: true,
    //   changeOrigin: true, // Change the origin of the host header to target URL
    //   target: webpackDevServerUrl,
    // });
    const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
    
    /**
     *
     * @param {string} filePath
     * @param {string} entryIndex
     * @returns {webpack.Configuration}
     */
    function createConfig(filePath, entryIndex) {
      return {
        mode: isDevelopment ? "development" : "production",
        devServer: {
          client: { overlay: false },
          port: "3200",
        },
        entry: {
          [entryIndex]: "./" + filePath,
        },
        output: {},
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.tsx?$/,
              include: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
              use: "babel-loader",
            },
          ],
        },
        plugins: [
          isDevelopment && new ReactRefreshPlugin(),
          new ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin(),
          // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          //   filename: './index.html',
          //   template: './public/index.html',
          // }),
        ].filter(Boolean),
        resolve: {
          extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        },
      };
    }
    const config = createConfig("./src/index.tsx", "main");
    let devServer = new webpackDevServer(config.devServer, webpack(config));
    
    const app = express();
    
    (async () => {
      await devServer.start();
    
      app.use(async (req, res, next) => {
        const requestedFile = req.path.substring(1);
        if (requestedFile.includes("js")) {
          const jsFile = requestedFile.replace("/", "");
          const entryIndex = requestedFile.replace("/", "").replace(".js", "");
          const tsxFile =
            requestedFile.replace("/", "").replace(".js", "") + ".tsx";
          const filePath = await new Promise((resolve) =>
            searchFile("./", tsxFile, (fp) => {
              resolve(fp.replaceAll("\\", "/"));
            })
          );
    
          const newConfig = createConfig(filePath, entryIndex);
          console.log("Stopping webpack-dev-server..");
          await devServer.stop();
          devServer = new webpackDevServer(newConfig.devServer, webpack(newConfig));
          await devServer.start();
          console.log("Serving only " + filePath + " to webpack-dev-server.");
    
          const compiledText = await (
            await fetch("http://localhost:3200" + "/" + jsFile)
          ).text();
          //   console.log(response);
          res.send(compiledText);
        } else {
          next();
        }
      });
      app.use("/", proxy("http://localhost:5501"));
      app.use("/", proxy("http://localhost:3200", {}));
    
      // // Apply the WebSocket proxy middleware to all WebSocket requests
      // app.use("/sockjs-node", wsProxy); // Adjust this path based on your webpack dev server configuration
    
      // // Create a proxy middleware for all other requests (HTTP)
      // const httpProxyMiddleware = httpProxy(webpackDevServerUrl, {
      //   proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
      //     return req.url; // Resolve proxy path based on the original request URL
      //   },
      // });
    
      // // Apply the HTTP proxy middleware to all non-WebSocket requests
      // app.use(httpProxyMiddleware);
      app.listen(3000, () => {
        console.log("Server running on http://localhost:3000/");
      });
    })();
    
    function searchFile(dir, fileName, callback) {
      //read the contents of the directory
      fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
        if (err) throw err;
    
        // search through the files
        for (const file of files) {
          // build the full path of the file
          const filePath = path.join(dir, file);
    
          // get the file stats
          fs.stat(filePath, (err, fileStat) => {
            if (err) throw err;
    
            // if the file is a directory, recursively search the directory
            if (fileStat.isDirectory()) {
              searchFile(filePath, fileName, callback);
            } else if (file.endsWith(fileName)) {
              // if the file is a match, call the callback with the file path
              callback(filePath);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }


The trick here being that I have to change the entry property and the output filename property for the config and re-run the webpack dev-server.
When I try this approach it works partially, it doesn't pick up the new changes that I make.
What I have tried is the following :
    // localhost:3000 <-- Express server to receive .js files
    // localhost:3200 <-- Webpack dev server
    // localhost:5501 <-- Server which contains the root .html/.aspx elements

So how do I approach this problem while maintaining hot-module-reloading? As I want to integrate react with my old asp.net web forms project to ease down my UI tasks. I know it's not the correct approach to use asp.net webforms for UI, but I was kind of forced to work with such dependency.
